# cvLoadImage works with string constant but not c_str()

Tags: opencv

I am using `cvloadimage` to open an image in my program. The images are in a external directory, generated using the current time in the filename.

When I try to load images in this way:

```
IplImage *image = cvLoadImage(path.c_str,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

the image structure will be NULL and the application will stop with q segmentation fault.
When I try to load an image this way:

```
IplImage *image = cvLoadImage("path/images/image_2012_11_25.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

then it works great.

Is the problem that `cvLoadImage` can't accept any type of text, only `const char*`? 
But `c_str()` converts string to `char*`, right?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `path.c_str()` in your code?

Comment: Originally it is, there is a typos.You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: I checked according to your comment and I coudn't find any such problem, both method worked alike: `string name("path\\test.png"); IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(name.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); cvShowImage("Win", img);` And `IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("path\\test.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); cvShowImage("Win", img);` I am using `OpenCV 2.4.5` I will suggest you to use `cv::Mat` etc C++ OOPs constructs if your are using C++.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with writing into a file so I used the code below:

```
const char *M=s.c_str();
 file.write(M,s.size());
```

hope it works...